# Share Video component between screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a screen with a thumbnail sized `<Video>` playing and then transition to another screen where the video takes up the full window via react-navigation.

Is there a way to preserve that video element and transfer it to the new screen? If I render a new `<Video>`, it adds a delay as the video has to buffer before it can start playing rather than being a seamless transition where I can animate as the resize happens.

Comment: I'd be really tricky to pull off but, depending on your layout, the only way I can think of is actually having the video player overlay the whole `react-navigation` layer and pass the controls through the react navigators `screenProps`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be supported in a future version of react-navigation once RFC 17 is completed:
https://github.com/react-navigation/rfcs/issues/17

In the meantime, there is a separate project called Fluid Transitions to support it:
https://github.com/fram-x/FluidTransitions

I have not gotten to test whether this will work for videos yet, but it does allow shared transitions for images, etc.